# Text input creates selection options

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

Was able to get the input to create an output. However, can't seem to get the text you type in the input to show up as the option's dropdown name.

```js
function addSku() {
  let tableRef = document.getElementById('sku_list');
  let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
  let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let newText = document.createTextNode(document.querySelector('#sku_input').value);
  var op = new Option();
  op.value = newText;
  op.text = newText;
  sku_dropdown.options.add(op);
  newCell.appendChild(newText);
}

document.getElementById('add_sku').onclick = addSku;
```

```html
<form>
  <input required id="sku_input" type="text" placeholder="Sku #" />
  <input id="add_sku" name="add_sku" value="Add" type="button" />
</form>

<table>
  <tbody id="sku_list">
    <tr>
      <th>Sku</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<form>
  <select id="sku_dropdown">
    <option disabled>Select Sku</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/8pq7d5aw/2/

Comment: @adrift added a link

Comment: Where is `addRow()` coming from? That's not a valid method in JS.

Comment: sorry, that was not needed. Just edited.

Comment: `op.text = newText;` you're treating an html object as text, change it to `op.text = document.querySelector('#sku_input').value;` i suggest you save the input value in a variable because you gonna be using it a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple mistakes in your code.

```
let newText = document.createTextNode( document.querySelector('#sku_input').value);
var op = new Option();
op.value = newText;
op.text = newText;
```

In the above you're creating a new TextNode. This is actually a HTML element so you can't assign it to the Option's **.value** and **.text** properties.
Do it like this instead:

```
let newText = document.createTextNode( document.querySelector('#sku_input').value);
var op = new Option();
op.value = document.querySelector('#sku_input').value;
op.text = document.querySelector('#sku_input').value;
```

Lastly

```
sku_dropdown.options.add(op);
```

sku_dropdown is undefined so get the actual html element using it's id

```
document.getElementById('sku_dropdown').options.add(op);
```

Comment: No problem - glad I could help! =)

Answer (score 0):

```js
function addSku() {
  let tableRef = document.getElementById('sku_list');
  let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
  let newCell = newRow.insertCell(0);
  let newText = document.querySelector('#sku_input').value;
  var op = new Option();
  op.value = newText;
  op.text = newText;
  sku_dropdown.options.add(op);
  newCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(newText));
 
}
console.log(document.getElementById('add_sku'))
document.getElementById('add_sku').addEventListener('click', addSku);
```

```html
<form>
  <input required id="sku_input" type="text" placeholder="Sku #" />
  <input id="add_sku" name="add_sku" value="Add" type="button" />
</form>

<table>
  <tbody id="sku_list">
    <tr>
      <th>Sku</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<form>
  <select id="sku_dropdown">
    <option disabled>Select Sku</option>
  </select>
</form>
```